# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 server not starting on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bits

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use Worklight on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bits.
I am using Eclipse 4.3.1 64 bits.

I tried adjusting jvm.options file to fix that, but I am having tons of errors.

I am also using the JDK 8 update 5 for Windows 64 bits.

Here is my jvm.options file content:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dwas.debug.mode=true
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=10777
-Dcom.ibm.websphere.ras.inject.at.transform=true
-Dos.name=Windows 8
-Xmx1024M
```

And here are the errors I have:

```
[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/NotificationBroadcasterSupport$1 with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/JmxMBeanServer with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/SunJmxMBeanServer with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/ClassLoaderRepositorySupport with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
........

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/NamedObject with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/ObjectInstance with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/JmxMBeanServer$3 with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/MalformedObjectNameException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager$1.platformMBeanServerCreated(FrameworkManager.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServer.invokePlatformMBeanServerCreated(PlatformMBeanServer.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.notifyListeners(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServer(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:43)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startLocalConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.agentmain(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.local.LocalConnectorActivator$LocalConnectorHelper$1.run(LocalConnectorActivator.java:65)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/remote/MBeanServerForwarder with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:50)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager$1.platformMBeanServerCreated(FrameworkManager.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServer.invokePlatformMBeanServerCreated(PlatformMBeanServer.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.notifyListeners(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServer(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:43)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startLocalConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.agentmain(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.local.LocalConnectorActivator$LocalConnectorHelper$1.run(LocalConnectorActivator.java:65)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/InstanceNotFoundException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager$1.platformMBeanServerCreated(FrameworkManager.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServer.invokePlatformMBeanServerCreated(PlatformMBeanServer.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.notifyListeners(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServer(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:43)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startLocalConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.agentmain(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.local.LocalConnectorActivator$LocalConnectorHelper$1.run(LocalConnectorActivator.java:65)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/MBeanRegistrationException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager$1.platformMBeanServerCreated(FrameworkManager.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServer.invokePlatformMBeanServerCreated(PlatformMBeanServer.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.notifyListeners(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServer(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:43)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startLocalConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.agentmain(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.local.LocalConnectorActivator$LocalConnectorHelper$1.run(LocalConnectorActivator.java:65)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/InstanceAlreadyExistsException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager$1.platformMBeanServerCreated(FrameworkManager.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServer.invokePlatformMBeanServerCreated(PlatformMBeanServer.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.notifyListeners(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServer(PlatformMBeanServerBuilder.java:43)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startLocalConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.agentmain(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.local.LocalConnectorActivator$LocalConnectorHelper$1.run(LocalConnectorActivator.java:65)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/lang/management/PlatformComponent with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/lang/management/PlatformComponent$1 with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/lang/management/PlatformComponent$MXBeanFetcher with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
....


[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/management/CompilationImpl with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/management/MemoryImpl with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/management/NotificationEmitterSupport with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/management/StandardEmitterMBean with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/lang/management/MemoryUsage with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

......

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/rmi/NoSuchObjectException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/rmi/transport/ConnectionOutputStream with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/rmi/server/MarshalOutputStream with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/management/ConnectorAddressLink with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class sun/management/counter/Units with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/transaction/TransactionRolledbackException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/util/concurrent/Executors$DefaultThreadFactory with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/security/auth/login/LoginException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/transaction/InvalidTransactionException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/transaction/xa/XAResource with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

.....

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/transaction/xa/XAException with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/sql/ConnectionEventListener with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/sql/StatementEventListener with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class org/ietf/jgss/GSSName with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class java/lang/Math$RandomNumberGeneratorHolder with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at [internal classes]
```

Any one have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** *Worklight does not support JDK 8 at this time.*
You will need to downgrade to JDK 7 for things to properlyt work.

---

In your question you do not explain at which stage does this error occur.

1. Does it happen when you try to start the Worklight Development Server?
2. Does it happen when you try to perform a certain action, such as Build or Deploy?
3. Does it happen with a fresh, new, project or with any project?

Did you try with JDK 7? In tests done, everything works with this version of JDK in Windows 8.x and Eclipse.

You can also check if this is Eclipse-related or Worklight Server-related by starting the Liberty application server independently.
Navigate to your Eclipse installation folder > plugins > com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (or similar for you) > liberty > wlp > bin > server.bat